# Proposed change by Anonymous User

Tags: discussion

This happened when I was reviewing **Suggested Edits**. Usually, we can see which user suggested that edit. But, in the place of user, it was written: **proposed 28 mins ago by an anonymous user**.

When does an edit show that it is proposed by an anonymous user?

Does it mean that any random user who is not logged-in can suggest an edit?

Comment: How do you know that it is not possible?

Comment: @CodyGray i tried editing in incognito mode, where i was not logged in, It didn't show any option of editing the question

Comment: You didn't see the "improve this question" link when not logged in? That's what it should say, rather than "edit"

Comment: Anonymous users can't edit on Meta. In fact, no one can suggest edits. Are you sure you were trying on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @CodyGray yes i am sure, i was trying on Stack Overflow

Comment: @yellowantphil Yep, that makes sense, no bug there. :)

Comment: @RaviShankar Some questions don't have the _improve this question_ link. I think there's a minimum time limit or view limit to the post. Try visiting an old question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48/multiple-submit-buttons-in-an-html-form).